# What's the best way of getting rows with minimum value in specific column from data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, minimum, data-analysis

I have the `my_data_frame` data frame in R language:

```
s1 = c("a1", "b1", "a2", 'c5', 'b2', 'u8') 
b2 = c(3, 6, 1, 5, 2, 1)
d3 = c(T, F, F, T, F, T)
my_data_frame = data.frame(s1, b2, d3)
print (my_data_frame)
```

There is the following result:

```
  s1 b2    d3
1 a1  3  TRUE
2 b1  6 FALSE
3 a2  1 FALSE
4 c5  5  TRUE
5 b2  2 FALSE
6 u8  1  TRUE
```

What's the best way of getting rows with minimum value from column `b2` of this data frame?
After the execution the result must be the following:

```
  s1 b2    d3
3 a2  1 FALSE
6 u8  1  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
my_data_frame[my_data_frame$b2 == min(my_data_frame$b2),]
#  s1 b2    d3
#3 a2  1 FALSE
#6 u8  1  TRUE
```